# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

The following problem appears in my console after I execute the code and introduce the first cota `l[i].cota = sc.nextLine()`;

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at exercicio6.introlivros(exercicio6.java:18)
>   at exercicio6.main(exercicio6.java:9)

can anyone tell me what's the issue?

Here is my code

```
public class exercicio6 {
    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        livro l[] = new livro[200];
        l = introlivros();
        apagarbase(l);

    }

    public static livro[] introlivros() {
        int i = 0;
        livro l[] = new livro[200];
        do {
            System.out.print("Introduza a cota:");
            l[i].cota = sc.nextLine();
            if (l[i].cota.length() == 0)
                break;
            do {
                System.out.print("Introduza o autor:");
                l[i].autor = sc.nextLine();
            } while (l[i].autor.length() < 40);
            System.out.print("Introduza o titulo:");
            l[i].titulo = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduza a data:");
            System.out.println("Dia:");
            l[i].data[0] = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Mes:");
            l[i].data[1] = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ano:");
            l[i].data[2] = sc.nextInt();
            i++;
        } while (i < 200);
        return l;
    }

    public static void remover(livro l[]) {
        String cota1 = new String();
        boolean verificar = false;

        do {
            cota1 = sc.nextLine();
            if (cota1.length() != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                    if (cota1 == l[i].cota) {
                        l[i].cota = "";
                        break;
                    }
                    if (cota1 != l[i].cota) {
                        verificar = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (cota1.length() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Introduza a cota de novo!");
            }
            if (verificar == true) {
                System.out.println("Esse livro não eciste!");
            }

        } while (cota1.length() == 0);

    }

    public static void apagarbase(livro l[]) {
        livro p[] = new livro[200];
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            l[i].cota = null;
            l[i].autor = null;
            l[i].titulo = null;
            l[i].data[0] = 0;
            /*
             * l[i].data[1]=null; l[i].data[2]=null; l[i].estado[0]=null;
             */
        }
    }

}

class livro {
    String cota = new String();
    String autor = new String();
    String titulo = new String();
    int data[] = new int[3];
    char estado[] = new char[1]; // Requisitado R, Livre L, Condicionado C;
}
```

Comment: You've initialized your array, but not its elements.

Comment: Before posting on here about run time errors you receive, it is always a good idea to search for information about what the error means. This will save you time, as questions such as these have been asked over and over and over and over ....

Answer (score 0):

Here you are instantiating your array:

```
livro l[] = new livro[200];
```

However here you are attempting to access an element containing an object that does not exist yet:

```
l[i].cota = sc.nextLine();
```

You need to loop through and instantiate a new object at EVERY element. Either use a for loop or Array.fill.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above - objects are initialized to null

A quick way of populating an array is -

```
livro l[] = new livro[200];
Arrays.fill(l, new livro());
```